# Como permitir que el siguiente codigo permita la entrada de polinomios mayores a 9?

Tags: python, regex

Estoy utilizando re para poder filtrar e ir extrayendo los coeficientes y exponentes de cada termino.

El problema con el que me encuentro es que al ingresar un polinomio de grado 10 o mayor no me funciona el código que utilizo.

Por ej: `10x^5+7x^11-5x`
traera la siguiente lista: `[0.0 , -5.0 , 7 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 10]`

El inconveniente seria en el segundo término, ya que sólo toma el primer caracter que es el 1 y lo asigna como si fuera el término de grado uno, cuando deberia de ser de grado 11 y como es el mayor, deberían crearse 12 elementos en la lista.

```
import re

def leepol(entrada):
  regexp = r"(-?\d*)(x?)(?:(?:\^)(\d))?"
  c = {}
  for coef, x, exp in re.findall(regexp, entrada):
    # print(coef, x, exp)
    if not coef and not x:
      continue
    if x and not coef:
      coef = '1'
    if x and coef == "-":
      coef = "-1"
    if x and not exp:
      exp = '1'
    if coef and not x:
      exp = '0'
    exp = ord(exp) & 0x000F
    c[exp] = float(coef)
  grado = max(c)
  coeficientes = [0.0] * (grado+1)
  for g, v in c.items():
    coeficientes[g] = v
  return coeficientes

polinomio = leepol(input())
print(polinomio)
```

Comment: Tienes `(?:\^)(\d)` por lo que sólo va a tomar UN dígito después del símbolo de exponente, ¿no?

Comment: Como propones que lo ponga?

Answer (score 2):

A mí me gusta usar https://pythex.org/ para probar esas expresiones regulares. Probar ahí me dice que

- Estás ignorando el signo `+`
- Estás leyendo sólo un caracter si el exponente tiene más de un dígito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es útil también revisar [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) de python sobre expresiones regulares. Ahí dice

> \d
>
> Matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the class [0-9].

Que confirma nuestra segunda sospecha

Algo como `(\+?-?\d*)(x?)(?:(?:\^)(\d+))?` en la expresión regular debería funcionar mejor.

Después de eso, debes cambiar la forma como procesas ese exponente (usas `ord` y eso requiere un caracter, así que va a fallar)

Comment: Y como podria procesar el exponente?

Comment: @Juan convierterte el string en entero con [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: Iba a decir más o menos lo mismo que tu. Así que creo que una respuesta diciendo lo mismo sería innecesario. Solo quiero agregar que prefiero la expresión: `([+-]?)(?:\s*)(\d*)(x?)((?:\^)?(\d+)?` y sería más cómodo. Solo sería agregar una variable para el signo. [Así](https://ideone.com/cFWAMK)

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: A partir de aqui puedo tratar como si fuese una lista de enteros normal no?

Comment: Y una ultima consulta, puedo limitar el grado del polinomio dentro de regexp? por ejemplo si deseo que solo ingresen hasta un polinomio de grado N, ya que vi que con las expresiones regulares se pueden utilizar rangos..Y si se puede como seria?

Comment: @JuanAndresGonzalezArevalos. Dividir para reinar. Usa una exp. reg. que reconoce cualquier grado y luego repasa el resultado para chequear las condiciones adicionales, como el grado del polinomio.

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución usando la expresión regular que reconoce un término como 10x^5 y también 10x por si solo

```
(\d+)x(?:\^(\d+)|)
```

Las partes son:

- `(\d+)` Reconoce un valor de 1 o más dígitos (el coeficiente).
- `x` Reconoce la letra "x".

`(?: ... )` Son paréntesis que **no** son un grupo de captura. Se usan para forzar a elegir entre dos patrones separados por una barra `|`:

- `\^(\d+)` Reconoce y captura un exponente explicito, o
- Nada (exponente cero).

Aplicando el patrón al polinomio obtenemos una lista de tuplas (coeficiente, exponente)

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(\d+)x(?:\^(\d+)|)")
poli = "10x^5+7x^11-5x"
m = patron.findall(poli)
print(m)
```

produce:

```
[('10', '5'), ('7', '11'), ('5', '')]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Edición: Versión completa

El siguiente patrón lo reconoce todo:

```
(\d+)x(?:\^(\d+)|)(?:(\D+|))
```

Es el mismo anterior, agregando el patrón opcional `\D+`, que vendría correspondiento a la operación entre los términos.

Aquí aplicamos el mismo principio `(?: ... )` para forzar a elegir entre un no-digito y nada.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(\d+)x(?:\^(\d+)|)(?:(\D+|))")
poli = "10x^5+7x^11-5x"
m = patron.findall(poli)
print(m)
```

produce cada coeficiente con su exponente y el operador que le sigue:

```
[('10', '5', '+'), ('7', '11', '-'), ('5', '', '')]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Una pregunta, una respuesta.